# moment js not converting utc to local timezone in edge and mozilla browser

Tags: javascript, momentjs

**I wrote below code and it works fine for chrome but it is not converting utc to localtime when i am using  Microsoft Edge and Firefox browser.**

```
var d = '2016-05-26T07:45:09.227';
    var now = moment().toDate()
    var dateStr = "";
     var localTime = moment.utc(d).toDate();
    var d = moment(localTime).toDate();
    dateStr = moment(localTime).format('D MMM YYYY');
    if (now.getFullYear() == d.getFullYear() && now.getMonth() == d.getMonth() && now.getDate() == d.getDate()) {
        dateStr = 'Today ' + moment(localTime).format('h:mma');
    }
    return dateStr;
```